# Protractor - When Async callback Timeout error occurs

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, appium, e2e-testing

During write the test code, sometimes I am getting very high-stung error: **-Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL**.  After struggle to fix this error, I found some solutions here and there such as ***Increase Time Interval value, Call done() func at the end of code block and so on***, but nothing works for me.

I'd like to know when this error occurs now to know the exact reason.

Comment: Do you have assertion statement like `expect()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is very common message when you deal with `async/await`. In like 80% it means that you forgot `await` statement somewhere and the other 20 is some mistake in your tests that does require deep analysis. You can use the following tips to improve your debugging process

1) Show more information about an error - put it into your protractor conf file.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', ({ message }) => {
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', `Unhandled rejection: ${message}`);
});
```

2) Install "protractor-console" plugin, to make sure there is no errors/rejections in the browser console (i.e. exclude possibility of issues from your app side) and add to your config

```
plugins: [{
    package: "protractor-console",
    logLevels: [ "severe" ]
}]
```

3) Debug your tests with Chrome as shown in [official guide](https://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging)

4) Use [HtmlScreenshotReporter](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter) - this one creates a really good report, well structured and intuitive

Those are the tools that could help you to spot the problems. I removed all my `Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine` notifications only when I spent sometime debugging every particular test I had. This is the only recommendation I can give you without reviewing your code.